# How to check convergence

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

Please help me how to proceed in this question is it correct if I use iteration formula and perform iteration....

Comment: Step 1: Read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Step 2: Ask a good question.  That includes formatting of formulas using mathjax, and (important) include what you have done so far.

Comment: In any case, the problem has a typo. As stated, it's not true. To correct it, one way is to change the definition of $f$ to
$$f(x)=3x^3 + 4x^2 + 4x + 2$$
Another possible correction is to leave $f$ as it is, but correct the iteration to
$$x_{k+1} = -x_k - 2x_k^2 - {\small{\frac{3}{2}}}x_k^3 - {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

Comment: The version with $...+1$ factorizes as $(3x+1)(x^2+x+1)$ and has a complex pair of roots with real part $-0.5$ which is not very optimistic for the convergence from the given initial point. The version with $...+2$ obviously has not that factorizaton and roots close to $-0.74487$ and $ -0.294\pm 0.899i$.

Comment: Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute the derivative of the iteration formula and find a bound on the interval around $-0.5$ where you can bound it by $1$. Then prove that that interval is mapped into itself and you have shown the convergence to the root.

For instance with $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$,
$$g(x)=-\frac13\left(1+\frac1{x^2+x+1}\right)$$
you get that $[-1,0]$ is mapped to
$$
-\frac13\left(1+\frac1{([-\frac12,\frac12])^2+\frac34}\right)=\left[-\tfrac79,-\tfrac23\right]
$$
and its derivative
$$
g'(x)=\frac23\frac{x+\frac12}{\left((x+\frac12)^2+\frac23\right)^2}
$$
has values smaller $\frac34$ so that the iteration of that formula is contractive.